# How to decrypt files infected with .lezp extension ransomware?

Tags: ransomware

What to do when someone's pc has been hit by a ransomware which has .lezp extension and how to decrypt the files that have been compromised

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware/ransomware support site. The linked post gives you the pointers for what to do next.

Comment: yeah i just checked that out .. thanks shroeder for the concern.